# Do I need to edge installation to run browser in my app

Tags: webview2

I load edge browser to open webpages in my application. I am distributing MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe to install the webview2 runtime.
(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section)

I am not sure that is enough or if I need to ship MicrosoftEdgeSetup.exe also with my software.

Do webview2 runtime guarantee that the edge browser works on all kinds of machines?
I could not find any docs. giving clarity on this.

Is webview2 runtime is enough to launch my application in production? Could anyone provide me a link to Microsoft docs on this or confirm what is required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe is completely enough for production deployments you do not have to explicitly install the Microsoft Edge Browser Additionally.

I would recommend reading this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution it will cover all your doubts as I had when I started.